# Embed Foreign Key Objects in JSON Response in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I would like to embed foreign key objects into my .NET JSON responses in my API. I come from a Rails background and formatting the JSON response to include any found foreign key records is fairly simple. However, I can't seem to find the way to do this. I have a foreign key relationship set up like the below models:

```
public class Person
{
[Key]
public int id {get; set;}
public string name {get; set;}
}

public class House
{
[Key]
public int id {get; set;}
public string address {get; set;}
[Required]
public int personId {get; set;}
[ForeignKey("peronsId")]
public Person person {get; set;}
}
```

However, when I run a GET request, I get the house in the form:

```
{
"id":1,
"address":"Middle of Nowhere",
"personId":3
}
```

When what I want is:

```
{
"id":1,
"address":"Middle of Nowhere",
"person":{
"id":3,
"name":"Some Dude"
}
}
```

Or some similar structure. How can I accomplish this in .NET?

Using .NET 4.5 Web API 2 with Entity Framework in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the navigation property `virtual`:

```
public class House
{
  //...
  [ForeignKey("peronsId")]
  public virtual Person person {get; set;}
}
```

If you  have not disabled the lazy loading behavior,EF automatically loads a related entity when the navigation property for that entity is dereferenced.

Another option is eager load the navigation property using the `Include` extension method:

```
datacontext.Houses.Include(h=>h.person);
```

I suggest you check this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-4) for more info about this topic